# php - Warning : mail() verify your SMTP and smtp_port setting

Tags: php, html, localhost, phpmailer

I was trying to make a working contact form using html and php but when i enter the name and email and message then click send, it shows this error
*I am using normal local host with php (in cmd : $ php -S localhost:4000)*

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>C:\Users\BKMH\Downloads\Yahya\i mustn't uplaod to mega but i need my files\Projects\Websites\Html\Interesiting\GoodDesignePortfolio\php\message.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
Sorry, failed to send your message!
```

and here is my php code: ( i am new to php )

```
<?php
  $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
  $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

  if(!empty($email) && !empty($message)){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $receiver = "yahya.bourouina.acc@gmail.com"; //enter that email address where you want to receive all messages
      $subject = "From: $name <$email>";
      $body = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\nMessage:\n$message\n\nRegards,\n$name";
      $sender = "From: $email";
      if(mail($receiver, $subject, $body, $sender)){
         echo "Your message has been sent";
      }else{
         echo "Sorry, failed to send your message!";
      }
    }else{
      echo "Enter a valid email address!";
    }
  }else{
    echo "Email and message field is required!";
  }
?>
```

I spent two hours searching but i couldn't find any working solution, please help, and **thanks**

Comment: You tagged this with `phpmailer`, I suggest you use it instead of `mail`

Comment: You're using PHP's internal web server, intended for testing of PHP code only. AFAIK It doesn't offer an SMTP server that you'd need for `mail()`. Even on a full service web server the use of `mail()` can be problematic. Use PHP Mailer.